# Fetch inner entities with unknown depth

Tags: java, jpa

I have a class `EntityA` that may contain a `Set<EntityA>` and I am not able to fetch all the entities at once using `@NamedEntityGraph`.
Is it a wrong design to try and fetch all the entities at once ? If not, is it possible to do so ? I would like to avoid using `EAGER` fetch. Another option I was thinking of was to use Spring `projection`.

EDIT :
I ended up doing like this:

```
private void initializeEntitiesA(Set<EntityA> entities) {
    for (EntityA entity : entities) {
        Hibernate.initialize(entity);
        initializeEntitiesA(entity.getEntities());
    }
}
```

Is it any good ? Given this method is called on a specific case, not every time you want to get `EntityA`without its sub-entities in full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to perform a dynamic number of joins on the database side, so there is no way to actually fetch all the entities in a single scoop. The quickest general way of doing this would be to make a single query per level, which is what JPA will do for you (not eagerly, but there's no additional cost associated with doing it lazily).

If you knew more about the specific data (for example that in 99.9999% of cases there are exactly three levels), you could perform a microoptimization by always starting with a triple outer self-join - and here, afaik, no JPA implementation will help you.

Generally, I think your design does not really have a point. If you have a lot of such data, consider a graph database.

Comment: Thanks, this is the first time I hear of a graph database. I will share this idea with colleagues.